# Is the following invariant coincide with the harmonic forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. The Hodge Laplacian is defined as follow
\begin{align}
\Delta:\Omega ^k(M)&\to \Omega^k(M)\\
\omega&\mapsto d\delta \omega+\delta d\omega
\end{align}
and every $\omega \in \ker \Delta$ is called a harmonic $p$-form.

> Is the following differential operator coincide with  Hodge Laplacian?
>   \begin{align}
> \Delta^2:\Omega ^k(M)&\to \Omega^k(M)\\
> \omega&\mapsto (d\delta)^2 \omega+(\delta d)^2\omega
> \end{align}
>   If the answer is negative then Is it generate new invariant such as betti numbers?

**Remark.** It is easy to see that if $\omega \in \ker \Delta$ then $\omega \in \ker \Delta^2.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel is the same because $\Delta$ is self-adjoint. Namely, denote by

$$ (\omega, \eta) = \int_{M} \left< \omega, \eta \right> \, dVol_g $$

the inner product on forms. Then $(\Delta \omega, \eta) = (\omega, \Delta \eta)$ for all $\omega, \eta \in \Omega^{*}(M)$ and so if $\Delta^2 \omega = 0$ then

$$ 0 = (\Delta^2 \omega, \omega) = (\Delta \omega, \Delta \omega) = \int_M \left< \Delta \omega, \Delta \omega \right> \, dVol_g $$

and so $\Delta \omega = 0$.

Comment: BTW, the operators $\Delta$ and $\Delta^2$ definitely do not coincide because one is a second order operator while the other is a fourth order... But the kernels are nonetheless the same.